# Individual Axios Call For Each Item In Array

Tags: reactjs, axios, render

I am not very experienced using axios calls with React and I am trying to make an axios call to get an array and then use that array to make an axios call for each item in the array. I am getting the array from the first call and then I am getting the array of objects from each individual call but after the state is updated nothing is rendered. Here is my code:

I tried to use a separate to update the state of the array of objects but that did not work.

```
state = {
    items: [],
    searchItem: "newstories",
    promises: [{}]
   };

 componentDidMount() {

     const { searchItem } = this.state;
     axios
       .get(
         "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/" +
           this.state.searchItem +
           ".json?print=pretty"
       )
       .then(result => {


         const topStories = result.data;

         this.setState({ topStories });

        let promises = [];
         for (let i = 0; i < topStories.length; i++) {
           axios
              .get(base + topStories[i] + extension)
             .then(res => {
               const newItem = res.data;
               promises.push(newItem.title);
             })
             .catch(error => console.log("Something went wrong"));
         }
         // Set the state of the array of objects
        this.setState({ promises });

       });
   }

 render() {

let counter = 0;

return (
  <div> 
        {this.state.promises.map(stories => (
          <li style={{ listStyle: "none" }} key=stories.id>
            {(counter += 1)}. {stories.title}
          </li>
        ))}
    </div>
     );
   }
 }
```

I want to be able to map and get each object and use the attributes of each object accordingly. Each object looks like this:

{by: "thinksocrates" id: 20004127 kids: […] score: 28 title: "OKR" }

The render isn't returning any of the titles but I am able to see them in a console log after the state is changed so I am not sure what is happening. I am guessing that I am getting the array of promises incorrectly but I am not sure how to use axios.all for this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this.setState({ promises });` will run before all promise is resolve. This is better way to slove it.

```
.then(result => {
   const topStories = result.data;
   const promises = topStories.map(story => {
     return axios.get(base + story + extension).then(res => res.data)
   })
   Promise.all(promises).then(data => {
     console.log(data)
     this.setState({ promises: data })
   })
```

Change the render

```
render() {
   return (
      <div> 
         {this.state.promises.map((stories, index)=> (
            <li style={{ listStyle: "none" }} key=stories.id>
              {`${index + 1}}.${stories.by}`}
            </li>
         ))}
      </div>
     );
   }
```

Comment: I am getting a stories is null after the setState.

Comment: (500) […]
​
[0…99]
​​
0: Object { by: "yarapavan", descendants: 0, id: 20019533, … }
​​
1: Object { by: "thehogrammer", descendants: 0, id: 20019532, … }
​​
2: Object { by: "jkuria", descendants: 0, id: 20019499, … }
​​
3: Object { by: "espeed", descendants: 0, id: 20019496, … }

Comment: I also added filler text until all promises are received and the boolean value is changed...  {this.state.isMounted === true ? (
              this.state.promises.map(stories => (
                <li style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
                  {(counter += 1)}. {stories.title}
                </li>
              ))
            ) : (
              <h3>Loading data</h3>
            )}

Comment: Yeah I am getting the same result after the state is update. It throws the error "stories is null"

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I just have lunch. One of story is null so it throw error
https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-meadow-3zpdu

Comment: you can see it on line 164. I checked  `stories` not null.

Answer (score 2):

you need here to use `Promise.all`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

your promise array fill with promises and not with objects to render them properly you need to wait for all response

moreover this action inside componentDidMount() will take an amount of time so it  will be better to considering initialise the state with a loader until all response retrieve

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, is there no way to preload from an API? I kinda don't want to use filler text.